# get item slelcted from llistview with multiple data in it from android activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

hi my problem is this: i want to make   activity in my app where u able to search for a person update a person or delete him at the same time 
now the search part is done and i display it in a list view 
now i want  when selecting a person from a listview u can fill those field and update the person my problem is getting the information from the slected item from the list view the list view contains the person name id and email and phone number here is the code

the layout for the listView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#76ba7e"
android:layout_height="75dp">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nom_id"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="nom"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/prenom_id"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nom_id"
    android:text="Prenom"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/email_id"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/prenom_id"
    android:text="Email"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/numero_tele_id"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/email_id"
    android:text="Numero telephone"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/person_id"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numero_tele_id"
    android:text="Numero telephone"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the custom adapter class

```
public class MembreAdapter  extends BaseAdapter{
private Context context;
private List<Membre> memb;

public MembreAdapter(Context context, List<Membre> memb) {
    this.context = context;
    this.memb = memb;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return memb.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return memb.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v= View.inflate(context,R.layout.display_member_row,null);
    TextView tid=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.person_id);
    TextView tnom = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.nom_id);
    TextView tprenom = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.prenom_id);
    TextView temail = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.email_id);
    TextView tnumero= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.numero_tele_id);
    tid.setText(memb.get(position).getId());

    tnom.setText(memb.get(position).getNom());
    tprenom.setText(memb.get(position).getPrenom());
    temail.setText(memb.get(position).getEmail());
    tnumero.setText(""+memb.get(position).getNumero());




    return v;
}
}
```

and finally the class that i want to all the work in

```
public class RechercheMembre extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText email,nom,prenom;
ListView listView;
Button rechercheButton,modifierButton;
BaseDeDonee bdd; int numero;
MembreAdapter mema;List<Membre> mem ;
String nom1,prenom1,email1,p;
int idp ;
Spinner spinner ;ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ada;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recherche_membre);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    bdd=new BaseDeDonee(this);
    mem=new ArrayList<>();

email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    nom=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.nom);
    prenom=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.prenom);
    rechercheButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button14);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listrechetche);
    modifierButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button15);
    spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.etat);
    ada = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.etat_de_personne,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    ada.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(ada);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             p  = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    rechercheButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(email.getText().toString()==null && nom.getText().toString()==null && prenom.getText().toString()==null){
                Toast.makeText(RechercheMembre.this, "il faut saisir au moins un champs ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
               Cursor c = bdd.FindMember(nom.getText().toString(), prenom.getText().toString(), email.getText().toString(),p);
                while(c.moveToNext()){
                    nom1= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nom"));
                    prenom1=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("prenom"));
                    email1=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("profile"));
                    numero=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("numero_tel"));
                    idp=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("ID"));



                    mem.add(new Membre(nom1,prenom1,email1,numero,idp));
                }



                mema= new MembreAdapter(getApplicationContext(),mem);
                listView.setAdapter(mema);


            }
        }
    });
    listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView iddsz = view.findViewById(R.id.person_id);




            modifierButton.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {


                        }
                    }
            );

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });



}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this.

```
listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        TextView email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email_id);
        String email = email.getText().toString(); // This is your email what you select
        Log.i("Email", "" + email);

        TextView person  = view.findViewById(R.id.person_id); // This is your persion id what you select
        String person  = person .getText().toString();
        Log.i("Person", "" + person);

        modifierButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                    }
                }
        );

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

Comment: TextView email = view.findViewById(R.id.txtViewEmail);
when i wrote that it says incompatibe type required text view found view view

Comment: I let your email id as txtViewEmail. What is your email text view id of list row layout?

Comment: its a textView do i need to edit my post and post the custom adapter full class and the list row so u can understand better ?

Comment: thank you so much i needed to use  onclickListner for my list view and the needed to add (TextView) to fix the error

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the people list (`List<Person>`) as a global variable.
Another int variable called selectedPersonId.
Then, You need to catch the index of the item selected in the list view.

```
listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectedPersonId = position;
    }
}
```

Finally, when you click the modifierButton you could get the correct person from your global list.

```
modifierButton.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Person selectedPerson = personList.get(selectedPersonId);
           //You can to implement the Parceable interface in your Person class to pass the selected person to another activity.
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: i edited my question can u please look at it and answer me again cause ur answer is a bit confusing

Comment: try this. First, move 'modifierButton.setOnClickListener(..)' outside of 'listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(..)'. Then, create a integer global variable  called 'selectedMemberIndex'. Now, you need to catch the selected index of the selected member.  The method onItemSelected, you can see a position parameter, that is the index. selectedMemberIndex = postition. Finally, in the method onClick of your modifierButton, when you click you could get the member of the selected index of the global variable. Member selectedMember = mem.get(selectedMemberIndex);